# Asp:table with Linkbutton in cells and page cycle

Tags: c#, asp.net

I always seem to struggle with asp.net page cycle and dynamically created controls.

I have a asp:table that is created in !isPostBack in page_load (i have tried creating it in page load, page_init onint)

the table is created with cells that container a LinkButton:

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
lb.Text = cabinet.CabinetName;
lb.CssClass = "child";
lb.Click += new EventHandler(btnChange_Folder);
lb.CommandArgument = cabinet.Id.ToString();
```

Now the problem is, whenver the Linkbutton is clicked, it doesnt fire and the table disappears.

I know its to do with the page cycle.

So my next action I try is to put the LoadTable() call outside the !IsPostBack block so its loaded everytime..

This seems to work, except it requires me to press each button twice for it to fire...

Comment: May be you are adding controls twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify an ID

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
lb.Text = cabinet.CabinetName;
lb.ID= "ID_youwant";
lb.CssClass = "child";
lb.Click += new EventHandler(btnChange_Folder);
lb.CommandArgument = cabinet.Id.ToString();
```